# How can one find the version of the javadoc executable?

Tags: javadoc

I would have thought that the javadoc executable would offer a `-v` or `--version` option that would print out the version of the executable. Most executables seem to offer this. For example, GNU make lets you type `gmake --version`. Even `javac` has a `-version` option that shows this information. But javadoc's `-version` option pertains to `@version` paragraphs, and its `-verbose` and `-help` options don't show the javadoc executable version. Is this an oversight? Is there another good way to find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc does not have its own version number, it is pretty much tied to Java JDK/SDK itself.

You can use

```
javadoc -J-version
```

or

```
javadoc -J-fullversion
```

to get version info on the underlying JDK or SDK.

Comment: Ah, so that's what this means:

`-J<flag>                  Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system`